# Entity Group Transactions for Azure BLOB?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

Say I need to retrieve 20 thumbnail images from Azure BLOB after a button click. I've read that blobs are accessed like so `http://<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<blob>`

A single GetBlob() request is charged at 1 transaction. Is this to say getting 20 images will cost, at a minimum, 20 transactions?

Is there a way to send a batch request such that it retrieves those images and is billed at 1 transaction?

I've read about Entity Group Transactions, but it sounded to me they are for Azure Table only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing akin to Entity Group Transactions with blobs. Each is accessed individually, burning at least one transaction (depending on blob size).

At a penny per <strike>10,000</strike>100,000 transactions, this will likely not be a major cost factor unless you're constantly downloading blobs. In that case, it might be worth considering some type of cache, to prevent excessive activity against Blob Storage.

One other workaround (hack?): If you're always grabbing a set of related blobs, you could store that related collection in a zip file, in a single blob. Not saying I'm in favor of this, but if you need to save transactions, at least it's an option (aside from cache).

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx), which describes storage and how partitions related to blobs and tables (scroll down to the **Partitions** section). The pertinent info for you: Each blob is in its own partition. With table storage, you're able to perform atomic actions on entities within a single partition (there are no atomic actions across multiple partitions). This is why you don't see atomic operations across multiple blobs.